# How to add parameter-hinting to pycharm with generic factory

Tags: python, generics, pycharm, factory

Given this factory:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class Factory(Generic[T]):

    def __call__(*args, **kwargs) -> T:
        return T(*args, **kwargs)
```

And a usage of:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(a: str, b: int):
        ...

foo_factory = Factory[Foo]
```

I would like to see parameter hints beyond *args, **kwargs in my auto-complete in Pycharm.  Here's an example of what I get.  I'd like to see a: str, b: int instead.

[image]

I'd like for this to happen automatically. How can I make this happen? I see that I can use ParamSpec, but it doesn't seem to work inside the context of **call**.